# working with figures in python notebook in os x

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to work out the best way to work with figures in ipython notebook. This is a problem on os x but not in windows.

I have worked out how to put figures inline and in separate windows. What I'd like to do is put a figure in a separate window, leave it open and keep working on the notebook. But it seems I have to close the figure window to continue working on the notebook. How can I continue working on the notebook without closing the figure window?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation was hard to parse, but I stumbled on the solution, which wasn't obvious to me.

On OS X, using ipython notebook, the magic command

%matplotlib osx

causes any external graphics windows to be interactive. That is, I don't have to type

show()

and I don't have to close the graphics window to continue working in the notebook.